# deleting properties in neo4j without any nodes

Tags: neo4j

I was cleaning up the db and I chose to delete all the nodes to get it reloaded. I deleted the nodes and links, and found the db had 1024 properties left. I have no nodes now. I cannot actually delete the properties. Can anyone help?

Comment: what do you mean by properties?

Answer (score 1):

Are you basing this off the web console? Those numbers are notorious for never being correct. It's impossible for the system to actually have properties without any nodes or relationships, however neo4j does use a lazy delete system, so properties aren't always removed at the time they are deleted from the file store, however it should be impossible for the system to access them.

Comment: Are you using the web console? As mentioned in my answer, the web console has a different way of calculating these numbers that is not always correct.